# How can I use the YouTube LivStreaming API to detect that a YouTube live broadcast has been deleted?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the [YouTube LiveStreaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs) to retrieve the list of lives and cache them in a database.

Can I use the LiveStreaming API to detect deleted liveBroadcast?
I thought that the lifeCycleStatus of a deleted liveBroadcast would be in the revoked state, but I was mistaken. I believe this is probably the status of cases that have been disabled by the YouTube admin team.

I don't think it is currently possible to retrieve deleted lives via the List API. Is this understanding correct?

Thank you.

Comment: By *retrieve deleted lives*, you mean that you already got their videos ids when they weren't deleted or you assume not to have them? It seems that you don't assume such, then hopefully afterwards a live got deleted we can't retrieve any information for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thank you.

The IDs of the live streams obtained are stored in the database.
So, by comparing all the IDs in the database with all the results of the List API, I will know which live streams have been deleted.

However, this process is costly and not smart.

I would like to know the deleted live streams at low cost by some mechanism like webhook or another method.